# how to determine user bandwidth on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, low-bandwidth

I need to determine user's bandwidth.I want to force user to read from local data if his connection is bad although he will download it.
I am doing this in Objective-C but if there a solution on Swift, It is okay.

Is there any library or any thing else to determine user bandwidth?

Comment: I don't know Objective C, but one way to determine the bandwith is to download a 50kb or 100kb file (e.g. image) from a website you trust and see how long it takes to download the file.

Comment: thanks @N.P. it is a good trick. but I will use it in the whole project that's why I need an efficient solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no any library for determine bandwidth in objective c. 
you can check bandwidth by downloading any small size file or open web page.
count time duration of file downloading.
then count

```
speed = size/time.
```

and delete that file. you should use delegate methods.

Comment: i am also searching the best way for this task. but still not found other solution

Comment: you can use EBPing (https://github.com/lmirosevic/GBPing) in order to measure the time needed open a web page.

Comment: Hello i am using GBPing its send log   ENT>   host: google.com, seq: 5, status: 0, ttl: 49, payloadSize: 56, sendDate: 2017-08-23 09:35:35 +0000, receiveDate: (null), rtt: 0.000000
2017-08-23 15:05:35.093 PingTester[3450:647345] REPLY>  host: google.com, seq: 5, status: 1, ttl: 49, payloadSize: 56, sendDate: 2017-08-23 09:35:35 +0000, receiveDate: 2017-08-23 09:35:35 +0000, rtt: 0.045040  what is the ,eaning of this